# Replace number with name of months

Tags: jasper-reports

I have sort of data which contains number.

`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,` to represent months.

I want to change it so when I preview the report it shows

```
January
February
March
April 
May
June
July
August
November
December
```

I've tried using `replace()`

```
.replace("1", "January")
```

When I run it, it doesn't work

Any suggestion?

Comment: what language are you using? Please post relevant code that you have tried.

Comment: It's java. I edit .replace() via Expression Editor

Comment: is the input a string or a list??

Comment: @CrakC I've tried .replace("CO","Complete")

Comment: @SalmaSulthanah plz show us the field jrxml code. you can use Text Field Expression to do it.

Comment: @ManiDeep is it the one in Expression Editor ?

Comment: @SalmaSulthanah yes. i have added it in answser have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Text Field Expression, Replace `$V{Month}` with your field Name

```
<textfieldexpression class="java.lang.String">
    (
        $V{Month}.equals("1") ? "January" : 
        $V{Month}.equals("2") ? "February" :
        $V{Month}.equals("3") ? "March" :
        $V{Month}.equals("4") ? "April" :
        $V{Month}.equals("5") ? "May" :
        $V{Month}.equals("6") ? "June" :
        $V{Month}.equals("7") ? "July" :
        $V{Month}.equals("8") ? "August" :
        $V{Month}.equals("9") ? "September" :
        $V{Month}.equals("10") ? "October" : 
        $V{Month}.equals("11") ? "November" : "December"
    )
</textfieldexpression>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. What I have done here is split the source string into an `ArrayList` of `String` and then used `switch case` to concatenate the names of corresponding months to a new string that is shown as the output.

```
import java.util.*;

class abc
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,";
        String res = "";
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
        for (String s : list)
        {
            switch (s)
            {
                case "1":
                    res += "January\n";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    res += "February\n";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    res += "March\n";
                    break;
                case "4":
                    res += "April\n";
                    break;
                case "5":
                    res += "May\n";
                    break;
                case "6":
                    res += "June\n";
                    break;
                case "7":
                    res += "July\n";
                    break;
                case "8":
                    res += "August\n";
                    break;
                case "9":
                    res += "September\n";
                    break;
                case "10":
                    res += "October\n";
                    break;
                case "11":
                    res += "November\n";
                    break;
                case "12":
                    res += "December\n";
                    break;
                default:
                    System.err.println("Invalid output");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was about the *JasperReports*. Your answer is not applicable (without using scriptlets)